# PHP MySQL - Select the ID with the highest number

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table where multiple records can be stored by the same user on a daily basis.

So right now I'm doing this:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE user_id = '$userid'
```

Now, what I need to do is to select the latest entry available by that user, something like:

The table has an ID field which is auto increment so, I was thinking something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `stats` WHERE user_id = '$userid' WHERE ID <- Is the latest..
```

How can I do that and select Where ID is the latest ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT * 
FROM `stats` 
WHERE user_id = '$userid'
order by ID desc limit 1
```

Comment: Great, doing this way you avoid the sub-select.

Answer (score 3):

You can do a subquery.

```
SELECT * FROM `stats` WHERE user_id = '$userid' WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM your_table)
```

See Abhik Chakraborty's answer if the higher ID you search is from the "stats" table. It's answer is a lot better :)

Answer (score 0):

try this query.

SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE postID=(SELECT MAX(userID) FROM `mytable`)